# Fourier series calculation

Tags: matlab, fourier, fourier-series

I have tried to solve, but do not know if the answer is correct or not.

A person has a periodic voltage input to a circuit. The input repeats itself every 0.02 seconds i.e. the fundamental period is 0.02 seconds.
The person measures the input with a voltmeter and finds that the input may be approximated by:

`Vin(t) = V0*exp(a*t) ; 0 sec <= t < 0.02 sec ;  V0= 2 Volts a = -100sec^-1`

Graphically the function may be represented by:

[image]
A)Write a mathematical expression containing an integral that may be used for calculation of the Fourier-coefficients of Vin(t).

B)Evaluate the integral analytically for the DC-term (often referred to as c0 ). Looking at the graph, how can you check if your answer is reasonable?

I know I need to use these formulas:

[image]

I've tried to calculate a0 and here I got approx 2, 
according to this matlab code:

```
v0 = 2;
a = (-100^-1)
T = 0.02
a_0 = (1/T)*int((v0*exp(a*t)),t,0,T)
```

`a0` calculated to `1.9998`

I stuck with the an and bn, because i'm not sure if that is correct or not...

```
an = ((2/T)*int((v0*exp(a*t))*cos(n*w0*t),t,0,T))
```

`an` calculated to `(20000*exp(-1/5000)*(exp(1/5000) - 1))/(100000000*pi^2 + 1)`

```
bn = (2/T)*int((v0*exp(a*t))*sin(n*w0*t),t,0,T)
```

`bn` calculated to `(200000000*pi*exp(-1/5000)*(exp(1/5000) - 1))/(100000000*pi^2 + 1)`

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  As the canned hold message says, it seems like you're asking for code written to a specification, which is off-topic for this forum.  Can you rephrase the question in terms of a signal processing question that would fit better with the forum? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is a lot easier if you use the Euler formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Then the integral simply becomes
$$X(n)=\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{2L}e^{(-a+i\omega)\cdot t}, a_{n}=real[X(n)], b_{n} = imag[X(n)]$$

which is pretty straight forward to solve